# Not able to Save Tweets during Twitter Streaming

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to stream tweets and save them from Twitter API using Twitter4j.

```
public class TwitterStreaming{

private static int count;
private static PrintWriter writer;  
private static PrintWriter writer2;
```

In Main Function:

```
TwitterStreaming.writer  = new PrintWriter("FF8Json.txt", "UTF-8");  
    TwitterStreaming.writer2  =new PrintWriter("FF8.txt", "UTF-8");

   TwitterStreaming.count=0;

    //writer.println("hello :)");
    //writer2.println("Check 123");

    StatusListener listener;
    listener = new StatusListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStatus(Status status) {

            TwitterStreaming.writer.println(DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status));
            TwitterStreaming.writer2.println(status.getLang()+" - "+status.getText());
            TwitterStreaming.count++;
            System.out.println("Count - "+TwitterStreaming.count);

            //To change the body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        } 
//Other Override functions are removed over here

        };
```

*FF8Json.txt* and *FF8.txt* both will be **empty**.
I have tried creating a function and sending the data to it and trying to write the data to the file through that function also. But it doesn't work.
How can I Solve this? Is there any other way to write the data into a file ?

But when I use **System.out.println** instead of **TwitterStreaming.writer** It works.

Whole Code over [**HERE**](https://codeshare.io/5DAR9r)

Comment: Are you getting any exception? Are you overriding other methods like onTrackLimitationNotice()? which keywords are you searching for?

Comment: I have overridden other methods and I don't get any exception or errors while running this

Comment: for reference sake, you can have a look at https://github.com/shubhamsharma04/jsonTweetDownload

Comment: If I run your code in my system I get the following exception : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not set to true.

Comment: I added jsonStoreEnabled(true) and tried it.
Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is going to be hard to find something in those files if you dont close the **printwriter** object..

```
 writer.close();
```

and please don't make everything static in the **TwitterStreaming** class

Comment: I have used close() function too.

I didn't want to use static.
At first, I tried declaring writer and writer2 variables in the Main function itself. It didn't work. So I thought to declare them as Static to solve the problem, But it didn't solve.